# Passing Delete Method Through sfGuard

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I have an application with people and groups in Symfony, where a person may have a membership with multiple groups. To remove a person from a group, I currently have an action in a 'groupMembers' module that takes a 'delete' method and removes the pair from a many-to-many entity 'group_membership'. The route currently looks something like this:

```
remove_membership:
  url:      /group-membership/:group_id/:person_id
  class:    sfPropelRoute
  options:  { model: GroupMembership, type: object }
  param:    { module: groupMembers, action: remove }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [delete]
```

To perform this action, the user needs to be logged in, so I restricted it using sfGuard in the module's security.yml:

```
remove:
  is_secure: true
```

So after clicking a 'remove' link, a user who isn't logged in is taken to the log in screen, but after clicking 'submit' the request is no longer a 'delete' but a 'get', meaning the similar add_to_group route is called instead!

```
add_to_group:
  url:    /group-membership/:group_id/:person_id
  param:  { module: groupMembers, action: create }
  ...
```

Is there any way to make sfGuard emulate a delete action and pass the parameters properly, or will I have to use a different route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to achieve this without writing custom code or editing code of sfGuard plugin.

See `plugins/sfGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib/BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php` (its `executeSignin` method for details) how sign in is handled.

`sfGuard` gets user referrer and performs redirect with [appropriate method of sfAction](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_redirect). This redirect is performed by using http header `Location`. So browser will use GET method to receive url content.

You can override default `signin` action and perform redirects from `remove_membership` route to an action which will use `sfBrowser` component to emulate POST request, but I highly recommend you to change routing scheme.

Comment: This is what I've had to do, unfortunately. Thank you for your help.